# ui route, node, express, 404 html files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I'm using Node, Express, Angular and ui.route. What I'm trying to accomplish is the following,

- have `index.html` as a master
- have `some.html` as partials

I setup the application to use `ejs` instead of `jade` (don't know if that matters at all)? 
The error I'm getting is that it can't find `localhost:3000/views/partial-home.html` 404, I tried all types of different paths in my routing,

```
(function(){
   var app = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/about');

          $stateProvider
            .state('home-about', {
                url: '/home-about',
                templateUrl: '/views/partial-home.html' 
            })
            .state('about', {

            });
       });
    }());
```

I do not have anything particular in my `app.js` file to handle html or in my `route/index.js`, currently I think it's using the `index.ejs` as well. What steps am I missing in using html and why could the error be with it not finding the `partial-home.html`

```
//routes/index.js
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

There are posts about this topic but none kinda sums up my two issues with using html files and why the 404. Appreciate all help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the solution**. It's just one of those gotchas. I was looking into my `app.js`, I had all the routing correct as Arbel was helping me with.

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

So I was looking though the file and it hit me when I seen this line, right that this is a static resource.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So I put my html files into `public/partials` and that was it. 
Now my `route` look like this

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home-about', {
            url: '/home-about',
            templateUrl: '/partials/partial-home.html' 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to 'mount' this `router` to the `app`.

```
app.use('/', router);
```

The `router` will be relative to the path that you mount it to, in this case the root `/`. You can mount it to any path and the `router` will be relative to that path. e.g.

```
app.use('/bar', router);
```

And your `router` 'mini-app' will be invoked when the application `get`s (or any other HTTP method) `/bar/` path.

Comment: Oh I totally missed that. Just so I got this clear. I need to add routes in nodes `app.js` file for all routes I set in my `ui.route` config?

Comment: If let's say `/views/partial-home.html` will be correct when you mount `router` to `/` (meaning e.g. http://localhost:3000/views/partial-home.html is the correct address of the partial) then no, because the path is correct, but if the partials are located elsewhere then you'll need another request handler for that different path.

Comment: I don't get why it isn't working for me. My html files are in `/views/`, I'm pretty much using a `express install` straight out the gate app, except I'm using `ui.router`, it all works fine when I'm using `<script type="ng-template">`, it's just making this files that gives me 404

Comment: Also make sure the `views` dir is set correctly like `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` (it's the physical address of the views on your disk, anything that is correct for you).

Comment: You are basically working on two parts: The front end which still needs the urls to be routed correctly by the server, and the backend which needs to know what to do with different request paths and a direction on where to get the template files it needs to render and send to the frontend.

Comment: the `views` path is set. Do I need to tell my `app.js` I want to use html files?

Comment: You need to set your view engine to `ejs` by `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can set your app view engine as html such that it can render html file.

var ejs=require("ejs");

app.set('views',//folder path of views);

app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'html');